# TikZ: node along decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hopefully a quick question but one I can't get to the bottom of. I'm using the code below to place a curly brace decoration, and though I can place text at it's halfway point I'd like to place on of my previous node objects.

The code is

```
\draw [thick,decoration={brace},decorate] 
    ([xshift=-0.1cm,yshift=0.2cm]H16.135) to
        node[midway,above] (bracket) {node[circle]}
    ([xshift=0.1cm,yshift=0.2cm]H112.45);
```

But where I've got `node [circle]` I'd like it to actually draw a circle node, rather than just display text. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw a circular node, use

```
... node[midway,above,draw,circle] (bracket) {node label} ...
```

The `draw` key strokes the outline of the node, and `circle` sets the shape.

A complete, minimal example:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (H16) {};
\node (H112) at (3,0) {};
\draw[thick,decoration={brace},decorate] ([xshift=-0.1cm,yshift=0.2cm]H16.135) to
node[midway,above=1mm,draw,circle] (bracket) {}
([xshift=0.1cm,yshift=0.2cm]H112.45);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If this isn't what you were after, please turn your snippet into a complete, minimal example that we can compile without any modifications, and see if you can clarify in any way.

Comment: That's it thanks! I had tried putting circle inside the node arguments but didn't realise I needed draw in there as well. Sorry for the simple question, many thanks for the clear answer. (I'll accept when I can in 5mins)

Answer (score 1):

here is a slightly different code. I removed `midway`, I used raise and changed the anchors

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (H16) {x};
\node (H112) at (3,0) {y};
\draw[thick,decoration={brace,raise=5pt},decorate] 
   (H16.180) to node[above=8pt,draw,circle] {} (H112.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]